# database in visual basic

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

```
studentname = TextBox1.Text
        Dim connection As SqlCeConnection
        Dim cmdString = "INSERT INTO [student](studentname) values(@studentname)"
        Dim cmdString1 = "select * from student"
        connection = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=gandharva.sdf")
        connection.Open()
        Dim command As SqlCeCommand
        Dim command1 As SqlCeCommand
        command = New SqlCeCommand(cmdString1, connection)
        command1 = New SqlCeCommand(cmdString, connection)
        command1.Parameters.Add("@studentname", studentname)
        r = command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader
        reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        Dim stdpaswd As String
        While reader.Read()
            stdpaswd = reader("studentname").ToString()
            MsgBox(stdpaswd)
        End While
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
```

THE DATABSE IS LIKE THIS
studentname
kartik
abhi
NULL

I am writing a database code to insert records using insert query.
The code works fine but there is no modified data in the table, its left with only the data entered manually to the table.

also in the messagebox it shows the the data inserted with insert query.
but the table is left with only 2 names which i have created manually.

Please help how to modify so that the table will have the entered data through the query?

Comment: That doesn't look like `VBA`.  Isn't it `C#`?  Apart from that shouldn't the `INSERT` statement be:  `"INSERT INTO [student](studentname) values('" & @studentname & "')"` - assuming @studentname is a variable.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returned the number of affected records, check its value, in your case it is the number of added records

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook, it is VB.Net

Comment: Can you please post the database structure. I am suspecting that the records are not added because you may have some fields with no default values that are mandatory.

Comment: Just so it's not lost in the convo @DarrenBartrup-Cook suggestion to stick single quotes around your parameter in your `INSERT` statement is almost definitely why you are inserting nothing. That is a string literal and it needs to be encapsulated.

Comment: You are not calling the command to insert the record, you need something link this: command.ExecuteNonQuery(), before your command1.ExecuteNonQuery() command.